# Changing VPN Parameter on GCP with CISCO ASA with IKEv2

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to setup an L2L IPSec  VPN connection between my VPN tunnel in GCP and my clients  remote VPN tunnel based on CISCO ASA 5520. The phase 1 was established but not the Phase2, hence the error "status: NEGOTIATION_FAILURE".

Reading the VPN Interops Guide for CISCO ASA "https://cloud.google.com/files/CloudVPNGuide-UsingCloudVPNwithCiscoASA.pdf" provided some configurations that the Client cannot meet as they only support IKEv1.

Can anyone please advise where I can make specific Phase 1 and Phase 2 changes as expected by the client. I prefer using the gcloud shell command.

Proof that Phase 1 was up is

```
LG-CISCO-ASA/pri/act#  show crypto isakmp | begin  my.gcp.vpn.ip
178 IKE Peer: my.gcp.vpn.ip
    Type    : L2L             Role    : initiator 
    Rekey   : no              State   : MM_ACTIVE
```

And Phase 2 was not up

```
LG-CISCO-ASA/pri/act#  show crypto ipsec sa peer my.gcp.vpn.ip

There are no ipsec sas for peer my.gcp.vpn.ip
```

On google cloud shell excerpts checking VPN status is below

```
...
status: NEGOTIATION_FAILURE
targetVpnGateway: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/amghouse-bct-sms-1/regions/us-central1/targetVpnGateways/amgh
ouse-bct-vpn1
...
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud VPN tunnel fails with mentioned error "status: NEGOTIATION_FAILURE" and gives error on GCP tunnel status "The peer gateway notifies: Proposal mismatch in CHILD SA (phase 2), Please look at peer logs."

Cause: mistach in cloud vpn and peer VPN gateway "traffic selector/encrytion domains/local proxies" ip address.

Resolution:
By default mostly Cloud VPN supports traffic selector CIDRs of 0.0.0.0/0 (any IP address) and peer VPN does the same. (for peer check their documentation).
In GCP, route based classic tunnel this is the case. but you can specify custom traffic selector only in policy based VPN in GCP and above mentioned error comes whenever there is a mismatch in  cloud vpn and peer VPN gateway "traffic selector/encrytion domains/local proxies" ip address.

So ensure, below setting is correct:
The Cloud VPN local traffic selector should match the remote traffic selector for the tunnel on your peer VPN gateway.
The Cloud VPN remote traffic selector should match the local traffic selector for the tunnel on your peer VPN gateway.

This will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can not make changes to ciphers for already created VPN tunnel. You would have to delete it and rebuild the tunnel.
However, when rebuilding the tunnel make sure cipher is configured as per GCP IKEv1 cipher guideline. As GCP IKEv1 ciphers are hardcoded in GCP side and it's not possible to change it.

As per GCP documentation [supported IKEv1 ciphers](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/resources/troubleshooting#ike_ciphers):

### For Phase 1

Encryption: aes-cbc-128
Integrity: sha1-96
PFS Algorithm (required): Group 2 (modp_1024)
prf:sha1-96
Diffie-Hellman (DH):    Group 2 (modp_1024)
Phase 1 lifetime:36,600 seconds (10 hours, 10 minutes)

### ForPhase 2

Encryption: aes-cbc-128
Integrity:sha1-96
Diffie-Hellman (DH):    Some devices require a DH value for Phase 2. If so, use the value that you used in Phase 1.
Phase 2 lifetime: 10,800 seconds (3 hours)

Make sure these ciphers are matching on both sides and following [this specification](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/overview#specifications).

For troubleshooting consult [this GCP document](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/resources/troubleshooting#ike_ciphers) and VPN gcloud command refer [to this document.](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/vpn-tunnels/)